# Directive doesn't fire on SELECT change event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this HTML code:

```
<select class="state ng-scope ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
    <option value="" selected="selected" class="">Seleccione un estado</option>
</select>
```

And I wrote this directive:

```
app.directive('state', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("element" + element);
            console.log("attrs" + attrs);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Why directive isn't fired?

Comment: What is `app`? The directive definition is fine, it should work.

Comment: Nevermind, I found where my mistake was, I'll answer my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I wasn't listen on `change` event. The right code is:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   console.log(element);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a ng-model on your select and then add a watch in your directive. Pass your variable into the directive and output your desired result. Pseudo code:

```
<select ng-model="myList" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
    <option value="" selected="selected" class="">Seleccione un estado</option>
</select>

<span state selectedItem="myList"></span>
```

and your directive might look like:

```
  directive('state', ['$http', function($http){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                myList: '=myList'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('myList', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    console.log(changed);
                }
            }
        }
    }])
```